# Does Swagger work with Struts to document REST api's?

Tags: java, swagger, struts-1

We have an existing Java 1.7 Struts 1 application. We do have some REST api's that use RX-JS (javax.ws.rs).

**Question**

Does Swagger work with Struts1?

Is there any documentation on how to configure this?

I have looked [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup), but I am not sure what version I should use?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "work with"? There's no integration(s) that work with *specifically* S1 as S1 pre-dates Swagger by a decade or so. If you're using one of the supported implementations it looks like you'd just hook it up according to the instructions for that implementation--it shouldn't *interfere* with the S1 stuff.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thank you for your reply. Do you know which implementation I should use (Jersey 1.X, Jersey 2.X, RESTEasy 2.X, Mule)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--you said you're using it already; which one are you using? JAX-RS is just an API; if you're running it, you're using an *implementation* of that API already.

Comment: I am using REST api's build with RX-JS (javax.ws.rs). So as a result I am not sure what documentation to follow here:  https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup

Comment: I have no way of knowing what implementation you're using. `javax.wx.rs` is just a set of annotations: JAX-RS is an API, not an implementation. If it's running, you're already using an implementation, and I don't know which one. You can find out by seeing what library you're using that contains the implementation.

Comment: The `javax.ws.rs*` classes come from a maven jar called `javaee-api-6.0.jar`. POM: `<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Ok. That's the API. (Hence the `-api` part.) That's not the *implementation* of that API, which is why it's marked `provided`, i.e., the *implementation* exists in a library, but at *compile* time the implementation is irrelevant. I'm not sure how else I can explain it. Maybe [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/jax-rs-spec-and-implementations) will help.

Comment: So that means that the server determines the implementation?  So I am using a JBoss server, does the server libs determine the implementation?  (Surely not? because then the swagger implementation won't be portable)

Comment: `your server should provide a JAX-RS implementation ` - how do I know what implementation JBoss is providing?

Comment: Looks like it uses RESTEasy I think.  https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1.x reached it's [EOL in December 2008](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html). There are only Swagger (an implementation of [OpenAPI Specification](https://swagger.io/specification/)) implementation for both JAX-RS as well as Spring REST.

There is NO implementation for Swagger in Struts framework as Struts was/is meant to be an MVC framework to build Java Web application. Yes, you can "hack" it to return behave like a RESTful Web Service but that wasn't it's intended purpose.